# What is a coded character set?

Tags: unicode

[Glossary of Unicode Terms](http://unicode.org/glossary/) defines *coded character set* as:

> A character set in which each character is assigned a numeric code point.

But from the linguistic point of view those three words could be understood in two ways:

1. (coded character) set = set of coded characters
2. coded (character set) = character set in which each character is assigned a code

I feel, like the first interpretation is invalid and couldn't be treated as a synonym for #2. In my opinion first defines a set of characters, that has already been converted to codes and it's more like *codespace*.

On the other hand the very same glossary has a definition for *Code Set*:

> Code Set. (See coded character set.)

Which led me to total confusion.

Could you please tell, if both of the interpretations are legitimate, or only #2 is correct. I am asking not only out of curiosity, but because I have a strong feeling, that the most widespread translation of this term to my native language is completely wrong.

Comment: It is mostly IBM-speak, just their word for "code page".  Depends on what vendor's products you use I suppose.  It is the antipode of Unicode and must die.

Comment: @HansPassant Won't agree on that: if you take a look at http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=63182 its called the UCS (Universal Coded Character Set). So I believe that term is in active use in our days.